# Display a summary of the scope context with vim

Tags: vim

Let say I am working on a code which look like this, in C for example.

```
function foo() {
  int a;
  int b;
  15 kLoC
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    15 kLoC
    if (bar) {
      while (true) {
        **cursor is here**
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like vim display a summary of the context where the cursor is, something like:

```
funtcion foo()
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (bar)
      while (true)
```

Comment: I hope `15 kLoC` doesn't mean '15 thousand lines of code'.

Comment: It is just an example. The meaning of 15 kLoC is scrolling to find where can be very hard in some cases.

Comment: Programming questions must go to http://stackoverflow.com .

Answer (score 2):

I finally find a plugin doing what I am looking for:

CTX: C context for Vim
http://chouser.n01se.net/ctx/

Answer (score 1):

You could do Code Folding to achieve this, take a look [here](http://aymanh.com/a-collection-of-vim-tips#Code_Folding)

Comment: It was not specified, but the purpose here is to make easier the understanding of an unknown source code. Code folding seems to not be the best solution.

Comment: Yeah in that case no, I was thinking of my own code and having a better overview.